# issue in jenkins integration with git

Tags: jenkins, path, continuous-integration

i  installed jenkins in `c:\program files(x86)\jenkins` and am trying to integrate with a `helloworld java` file. but when i first tried to build from jenkins, itself, its failed.

i went through this link : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bGqS0f4Utn4
when i compiled my java file, from the admin cmd prompt, its compiles successfully. but it failed within the `jenkins console`. 
I created a C:\workspace folder and saved the java file, there.

what am doing wrong ? why am getting the wrong path within the console output?

am getting the below error in the console output :

```
`Console Output

Started by user user1
 Running as SYSTEM
 [EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
Building in workspace C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\
   HelloWorld
[HelloWorld] $ cmd /c call C:\Windows\TEMP\jenkins6223662388306682118.bat

 C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\HelloWorld>cd C:\Workspace 

    C:\Workspace>javac Hello.java 
      'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
      operable program or batch file.

 C:\Workspace>java Hello 
'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
  C:\Workspace>exit 9009 
 Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
 Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- First, since you've installed JDK, make sure you've added in system level environment variable
- Set JDK bin path in Jenkins > manage jenkins > global tools configurations > jdk installations, then try
  mostly this option would help to resolve

Comment: @@jaydeep :: worked like a charm! yes, thats the issue. i went to jdk installations and given the path of my jdk11 path. then i built again , it shown me the                    
            C:\Workspace>exit 0 
Finished: SUCCESS